# SQL to Normalize a data table and create multiple tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I get 2 reports from a system which I have decided to process through Access using SQL. One report is called "Evals" and the other is "Con". Right now, the "Con" table is not normalized. There are fields called "User" and "User Roles" and the PK I would like to use is "CO_ID". For each instance of "CO_ID" there are multiple and varying "User Roles" and "Users". However, the "User Roles" are limited to a selection of 6. There could be multiple users for one role for each "CO_ID" though. This causes multiple rows with the same "CO_ID" related data.

The 2 reports are generated the same exact way, so the process will be the exact same each time.

I need to create a table with "CO_ID" and the other fields which stay the same for "CO_ID".

What is the best way to automate the normalization of this table?

I have tried to parse out the data using SQL, but I could not find a good way. I think something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CO_ID, [EVERY OTHER FIELD IS THE SAME FOR CO_ID]
FROM table1;

SELECT DISTINCT User_Role
FROM table1;

SELECT DISTINCT User
FROM table1;

SELECT DISTINCT CO_ID, User_Role, User
```

The first SQL command would create a unique list of CO_IDs, the second SQL command would create the lookup table for User_Role, the third SQL command would create a lookup table for User, the last one would relate CO_ID with User_Role and User. However, I was not sure how to create a primary key for all the tables to associate them together. This may not be the best way either, so I am open to ideas.

```
table1 = Con

CO_ID  Field1  Field2   User_Role   User
WA13    ABS 2019-02-13  Admin      User1
WA13    ABS 2019-02-13  Manager    User2
WA14    DB  2019-01-01  Secretary  User3
WA14    DB  2019-01-01  Manager    User2
WA14    DB  2019-01-01  Analyst    User4
WA14    DB  2019-01-01  Analyst    User5
WD15    ZZ  2018-11-20  Supervisor User6
WD15    ZZ  2018-11-20  Manager    User7
WD15    ZZ  2018-11-20  Admin      User8
WD15    ZZ  2018-11-20  Analyst    User9
```

What I would like the result to be
RESULTING TABLES

```
CO_ID   Field1  Field2
WA13    ABS   2019-02-13
WA14    DB    2019-01-01
WD15    ZZ    2018-11-20

User_Role
Admin
Manager
Secretary
Analyst
Supervisor

User
User1
User2
User3
User4
User5
User6
User7
User8
User9
```

Comment: Your table actually *is* normal. There are no columns in your lookup table other than the key, and to link your tables together you'd have to add the key column back. 

If you simplified your example here, try un-simplifying it a bit. What other columns do you expect in the lookup table?

Comment: The last 3 tables (1 table is missing that connects the User to the User_Role table), are what I would like the results to be. So table1 normalized, would turn into 4 tables as posted by @Olivier Jacot-Descombes down below. My question is, how do I automate the normalization of table1 in SQL (MS Access)? Every time I get table1 from the report, the same process will occur.

Answer (score 1):

You have an m-to-n relation between users and roles, because a user can have more than one role and a role can be assigned to several users. This m-to-n relation requires a link table between users and roles. Additionally, you are assigning a "Con" to each user/role relation.

```
role               user_role                user
+------------+     +----------------+       +------------+
| PK role_id |<----| PK, FK role_id |   /-->| PK user_id |
+------------+     | PK, FK user_id |--/    +------------+
|    name    |     +----------------+       |    name    |
|            |     |     FK co_id   |       |            |
|            |     +----------------+       |            |
|            |                |             |            |
|            |                |             |            |
|            |      co        v             |            |
+------------+     +----------------+       +------------+
                   | PK co_id       |
                   +----------------+
                   |    field1      |
                   |    field2      |
                   +----------------+
```

So, in the link table you have a compound primary key made of `role_id`,  `user_id` because each user/role relation is unique. Additionally, there is a `co_id` as additional information.

`role` and `user` and `co` are each on the 1-side of a relation. `user_role` is on the `n`-side of all relations.

Alternatively, it would also be possible to have the `FK co_id` in the user table. It depends what "co" or "con" stands for. Difficult to say without more background knowledge.

---

My assumption that a user can have several roles might be wrong (since, by looking at your data, is seems the user is more like an employee). Then you get this structure where each user is assigned one role and one co:

```
                          role
                          +------------+
user                 ---> | PK role_id |
+------------+     /      +------------+
| PK user_id |    /       |    name    |
+------------+   /        +------------+
| FK role_id | --
| FK co_id   | --           co
| name       |   \       +----------------+
|            |    \----> | PK co_id       |
|            |           +----------------+
|            |           |    field1      |
+------------+           |    field2      |
                         +----------------+
```

Comment: Your first schema looks like exactly what I want. That is what I am trying to do. However, my issue is the data comes out looking like "table1" which is the "Con" table. "CO_ID" is the unique ID that relates all my data together from the "Con" table and the "Eval" table, which I need to bring in the data. My "Eval" table has a unique list of "CO_ID", but it may not contain ALL the possible "CO_ID"s, whereas the "Con" table does. Also, my main problem is, how can I accomplish this in SQL after I get the "Con" table from the report. My goal is to automate this procedure of normalization.

Comment: Ultimately, my goal is to create a dashboard. I had 2 tables: "Con" and "Eval" joined on "CO_ID". "Con" has more records than "Eval", so I think the join in the dashboarding tool didn't work as anticipated. What I think I can do is actually just separate out "User_Role" and "User", and have 3 tables: "Con", "Eval", and "Users". I'll have one table on my dashboard showing the joined "Con" and "Eval" table and then a 2nd table which will just show the "Users" table. So when a person filters by a specific "CO_ID" they can see the specific users associated with it. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I usually create a sequence of stored queries in Access to perform data migration that I execute in sequence. Like `INSERT INTO user (name) SELECT DISTINCT user FROM Con WHERE user IS NOT NULL AND user NOT IN (SELECT name FROM user)`. Same for `role` and `co`. The last one is the most complex one it must join the source data by the `name` column to the `user` and `role` tables to get their IDs. Then it can insert the requires keys into the link table. Difficult to be more specific without knowing your exact schemas. It's still a mystery to me what `Eval` contains.